# Select rows if corresponding rows following criteria exist?

Tags: php, mysql

It may sound very confusing, I'll try make it simpler to understand.

There is a table, called "sessions."

The columns are: **rowid, time, user, action**.

What I want to do is select the last (highest rowids) x (let's say 4, it's not static at all) sessions with an **action of 1**, but only if a row doesn't exist with a greater **time** column with an **action of 0** and the *same user*.

So, as an example, only the bolded rows should be selected:

```
rowid(primary) time(epoch int) user action
**152 1393635884 42 1**
152 1392799204 75 1
152 1392799416 42 0 *<-- the bolded row is selected because this exists with a greater time*
152 1392802679 16 1
```

And if this helps, pseudo MySQL of how it might work

```
SELECT *
FROM sessions
WHERE action = 1 AND there is a row where time > this time and user = this user and action = 0
SORT BY rowid DESC
LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can do what you want using a `not exists` clause:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM sessions s
WHERE s.action = 1 AND 
      not exists (select 1
                  from sessions s2
                  where s2.user = s.user and
                        s2.time > s.time and
                        s2.action = 0
                 )
ORDER BY rowid DESC
LIMIT 4;
```